# Why does an indexed mysql query filtered on less char values result in more rows examined?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, innodb

When I run the following query, I see the expected rows examined as 40

```
EXPLAIN SELECT s.* FROM subscription s
WHERE s.current_period_end_date <= NOW()
AND s.status in ('A', 'T')
AND s.period_end_action in ('R','C')
ORDER BY s._id ASC limit 20;

+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                  | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | index | status,current_period_end_date | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   40 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

But when I run this query that simply changes `AND s.period_end_action in ('R','C')` to `AND s.period_end_action = 'C'`, I see the expected rows examined as 611

```
EXPLAIN SELECT s.* FROM subscription s
WHERE s.current_period_end_date <= NOW()
AND s.status in ('A', 'T')
AND s.period_end_action = 'C'
ORDER BY s._id ASC limit 20;

+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                  | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | index | status,current_period_end_date | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |  611 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

I have the following indexes on the subscription table:

```
_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
INDEX(status, period_end_action),
INDEX(current_period_end_date),
```

Any ideas? I don't understand why removing one of the period_end_action values would cause such a large increase in rows examined?

Comment: Row estimates on optimization plans are fraught with problems.  Clearly , MySQL is using different methods for the estimation based on the complexity of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

(I agree with others that `EXPLAIN` often has terrible row estimates.)

Actually the numbers might be reasonable (though I doubt it).  The optimizer decided to do a table scan in both cases.  And the query with fewer options for `period_end_action` probably has to scan farther to get the 20 rows.  This is because it punted on using either of your secondary indexes.

These indexes are more likely to help your *second* query:

```
INDEX(period_end_action, _id)
INDEX(period_end_action, status)
INDEX(period_end_action, current_period_end_date)
```

The optimal index is *usually* starts with any columns tested by `=`.

Since there is no such thing for your first query, the Optimizer probably decided to scan in `_id` order so that it could avoid the "sort" mandated by `ORDER BY`.